# git push --set-upstream origin master Not Authenticating With Correct Github Credentials

Tags: git, github, netlify, netlify-cms

I am trying to follow this tutorial to learn Netlify CMS (https://youtu.be/w_QbyxeQrkk?t=838) and when I am prompted to add my Github username and password and do it correctly it doesn't work. Even though I know for a fact what I typed is correct.
[image: git command]

I am not the most experienced with the command line.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to authenticate with your email account?

Comment: I just tried with my email address and typing my password again. Same result.

Comment: Are you trying to push to a correct repo? You can check it with `git remote get-url origin` command in your terminal, and confirm the printed repo is own by yourself.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. I am moving on to another example instead. If it's difficult just getting up and running it's just a waste of time. I'll just find another example to learn how to use Netlify CMS. Horrible instruction.